# How to implement the Google's "Advanced" Consent Mode?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

In the official documentation on the implementation of Consent Mode, Google says that there is an option to configure tags to send "pings" without personal information to Google, when the user refuses or withdraws consent for marketing and analytics (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9976101?sjid=7622132055315487185-EU#aivsbi1).

However, I have been unable to find any official documentation or blog articles that actually explain how to implement this Advanced Consent Mode.

I am mainly interested in how to do this implementation through Google Tag Manager and for GA4 and Ads tags/pixels.

What I have done so far is to implement only the basic mode, where absolutely nothing is sent to Google, if the user does not give their consent for marketing and analytics.

On a side note, I am fully aware of the legal implications of sending any data to google without user consent, but I need to know how to do this kind of "Advanced" implementation for very specific cases.

Comment: How do you currently use Consent Mode?  do you use a GTM template or a consent management platform?

Comment: @aliizadi I actually use both, a GTM template in some projects and CMP (CookieBot) in others.

Comment: @fs-doc did you manage to do this in the end?

Comment: @alturkovic I decided to speak to a Google representative. It is surprising how little information Google provides about it, even when you manage to talk to a human being. He basically referred me to the Cookiebot documentation, which says that "Advanced Mode" is implemented by relying solely on the consent tags that Google tags come with by default (e.g. ad_storage). I did a test and while the tags are executed before the user gives consent, in GA4 for example, page views are not registered until consent is given. I have not been able to check if this sends the so called "pings" though.